# How to use Sheet Modal in Ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In Ionic version % documentation shows the sheet modal in mobile view but code examples does not have any, how to use Sheet Modal, [View Source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/tree/main/static/demos/api/modal/index.html) link under the Mobile View, In Github Code it uses the latest Ionic versions.

And ModalOptions in Ionic version 5 only got this options

```
export interface ModalOptions<T extends ComponentRef = ComponentRef> {
  component: T;
  componentProps?: ComponentProps<T>;
  presentingElement?: HTMLElement;
  showBackdrop?: boolean;
  backdropDismiss?: boolean;
  cssClass?: string | string[];
  delegate?: FrameworkDelegate;
  animated?: boolean;
  swipeToClose?: boolean;
  mode?: Mode;
  keyboardClose?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  enterAnimation?: AnimationBuilder;
  leaveAnimation?: AnimationBuilder;
}
```

So how to implement the Sheet Modal in Ionic v5 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sheet Modal is Introduced in v6. Update grade your Ionic and then you can use it. 
see docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-action-sheet?

Another option is to use it as ion-select with `interface` and `interfaceOptions`, which is a fast and easy way if you don't care much about UI. For example:

```
<ion-select 
(...)
    interface="action-sheet"
    [interfaceOptions]="customActionSheetOptions">
    <ion-select-option (...)>(...)</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

And in ts add var:

```
customActionSheetOptions: any = {
    cssClass: 'your-css-class-defined-in-global-scss',
};
```